# Display table by merging two columns into one in HTML/CSS + JS (Datatables)

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I use https://datatables.net/ to render sortable and searchable tables on my webservice. My table gets very wide, because of many columns. I want to reduce the width by combining related columns into one.
The data of two cells of the same row shall be displayed in a single cell with a linebreak.

I want to transform this:

A B C
D E F
G H J

to this:

A B
...  C
D E
...  F
G H
...  J

Here is my JS example

```
<script>
var dataSet =
[
    {"name": "A", "absolute": 10, "relative": 0.1},
    {"name": "B", "absolute": 20, "relative": 0.2},
    {"name": "C", "absolute": 11, "relative": -0.1},
    {"name": "D", "absolute": 100, "relative": 0.3},
    {"name": "E", "absolute": 8, "relative": 0.04},
];
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $("#example").DataTable(
  {
    data: dataSet,
    columns:
    [
            { data: "name", title: "Name" },
            { data: "absolute" , title: "Absolute + <br> "Relative", render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                return row.absolute + "<br>" + row.relative; }},
    ],
    "columnDefs": [{ targets: 'data-sortable', orderable: false }]
  });
 });
</script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

In this example I use the "render" function for rendering two data columns into one.
The problem is, that the sorting will be done over the full/concatenated/rendered string. I still want to sort by both "absolute" and "relative" columns. The header of the table shall have two "sort"-buttons for that "combined" column.

Is there some html/css trick with hiding or colspan or whatever to achieve my goal?
I googled a lot and it seems like I have to write everything on my own in JS. I could not find anything for me. However, there are so many webpages with this feature of merged columns to one just for displaying.

[Here is an example of a table from comdirect bank. Here you can sort in one column two or three different values. This is exactly what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYrvi.png)

Comment: The sorting shouldn't happen on the rendered data but what was actually there unrendered, so that part is confusing me.  I also find it a bad design idea to combine two columns after the fact. Can you combine the data into a single column before it's sent to your table? That would simplify everything.  But datatables does have a way to control how or what is sorted, check this page out:
https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data

Comment: I edited my post to include an example.
Also thank you for the keyword "orthogonal-data". Unfortunatly this does not solve my problem. I could specify a "data-order" element, but I would also need a switch to sort either by the upper or lower data element in the cell.

Comment: So you want to sort by two different values but display both in the same column?  Semantically that just doesn't make sense to me. You could write the upper and lower values into two separate data-* attributes then put in a toggle switch that triggers a javascript function that places one of those data values into the data-order attribute. It's the only thing I can come up with.  Ah I see your example image now, that does help clarify what and why you're trying to do this.  I'll have to research this a bit, but I do know there is datatables extension that provides more advanced headers.

Comment: I'm not seeing a way to do what you want natively with datatables. Either something is going to have to be custom written or perhaps you can find an existing package out there other than datatables.  I did find where a similar question was asked on stackoverflow before and it never received an answer.

Comment: I do not need to use datatables, but it was the solution I started to use. It is very handy in converting standard HTML-Tables into paginated, multi-column-sortable and searchable tables.
Actually pageniation and sorting are the features I absolutly need. I am still "astonished" about the fact, that there is no simple solution to merge two columns for displaying, only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did not find an easy way to solve my problem...
I had to program javascript by myself.
Here is my solution: [github repository for my 'boss table'](https://github.com/svebert/boss-table)

Probably it is also possible to write some plugins for datatable, but I have no idea how this works. I am also a javascript-noob... So it was easier to write it on my own.